# Windows Docker - Spacy language model installation in python returns ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, windows, docker, importerror, spacy

I am building a Windows-based Docker image to run a Flask Application. For that, I need SpaCy language model to be installed. But I am encountering the following issue again and again and could not find any robust solution till yet.

**Runtime:** Windows Container (Docker)

**Error Trace:**

```
Step 6/9 : RUN python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
 ---> Running in 6f8f33207c8f
        Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python\lib\runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
        mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
      File "C:\Python\lib\runpy.py", line 142, in _get_module_details
        return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
      File "C:\Python\lib\runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
        __import__(pkg_name)
      File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
        from . import pipeline
      File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\spacy\pipeline\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
        from .pipes import Tagger, DependencyParser, EntityRecognizer, EntityLinker
      File "pipes.pyx", line 1, in init spacy.pipeline.pipes
    ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM winamd64/python:3.7-windowsservercore
COPY requirements.txt .
COPY models/* ./models/
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
RUN python -m nltk.downloader stopwords
RUN python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
COPY . .
EXPOSE 5000
CMD python waitress_server.py
```

**requirements.txt:**

```
Flask==1.1.1
future==0.17.1
httplib2==0.13.1
nltk==3.4.5
numpy==1.18.2
pandas
pandocfilters==1.4.2
pickleshare==0.7.5
regex==2019.8.19
requests>=2.13.0
requests-oauthlib
requests-toolbelt
scikit-learn==0.22.1
scipy==1.3.1
simplejson==3.16.0
urllib3==1.24.3
xlrd==1.2.0
zipp==0.6.0
lightgbm
sner
flask-bcrypt
waitress==1.4.4
spacy
```

**waitress_server.py:**

```
print("Hello World")
```

Other files are some trained NLP models.

**Note:**

- I have tried with multiple versions of windows images but no result
- I have tried with multiple NumPy and spacy versions
- Found an Issue on GitHub https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/4733#issuecomment-561123652 But it doesn't seem to solve the issue.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Note: This problem is very specific to Windows Container and if anyone could provide a working solution that would be very helpful since I have seen multiple issues like this lying in GitHub issues.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at [similar issues](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/5217#issuecomment-613928948) on GitHub, it looks like this is caused when running spacy on the native OS and not in a virtualenv. The recommended approach is to install and run the dependencies from a vitrualenv on the container.

To you this you need to manually activate the virtual environment by setting the VIRTUAL_ENV and PATH environment variables in the dockerfile.

```
# Set up and activate virtual environment
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV "/venv"
RUN python -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
ENV PATH "$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"
```

> from: [source](https://realpython.com/python-versions-docker/)

so your dockerfile should look something like this:

```
FROM winamd64/python:3.7-windowsservercore

ENV VIRTUAL_ENV "/venv"
RUN python -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
ENV PATH "$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"

# Set up and activate virtual environment
COPY requirements.txt .
COPY models/* ./models/
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
RUN python -m nltk.downloader stopwords
RUN python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
COPY . .
EXPOSE 5000
CMD python waitress_server.py
```

Disclaimer: I've not tested this myself, but seen various similar DLL issues involving python packages and running in a venv is the common solution.

Comment: Hi, I tried the above but this doesn't seem to solve the problem. Also, I think the issue is lying with the Windows image for Docker or spaCy should come equipped with all necessary runtimes.

Comment: ah shame this didn't work, as I said didn't try myself but did seem a potential solution... To your point of the windows image - that's correct this is what this solution is trying to achieve, by running spacy in a venv you're removing potential conflicts that can occur from running in the native OS. Is it a hard requirement to use a windows,  image? Servers are generally implemented as Linux containers and software is also usually built on unix boxes in the first place, meaning a) less likely to hit integration problems, and b) there is more community support available for issues

Comment: Yes, unfortunately using Windows containers is a hard requirement here. Otherwise, Linux is awesome and my code works well with Linux Container.